# How to get Signal strength (RSRP/RSSI/RSRQ/SINR), cell ID (LTE/3G/2G) of iPhone network

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

> I am using the code to get signal strength but it returning 0 every time.Please suggest me, how can i find signal strength.

```
func getSignalStrength() -> Int {

    let application = UIApplication.shared
    let statusBarView = application.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
    let foregroundView = statusBarView.value(forKey: "foregroundView") as! UIView
    let foregroundViewSubviews = foregroundView.subviews

    var dataNetworkItemView:UIView!

    for subview in foregroundViewSubviews {
        if subview.isKind(of: NSClassFromString("UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView")!) {
            dataNetworkItemView = subview
            break
        } else {
            return 0 //NO SERVICE
        }
    }

    return dataNetworkItemView.value(forKey: "signalStrengthBars") as! Int

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no official supported way to get cellular signal strength. May be some Private Api can do that stuff but its Illegal and app will be rejected